# Not saving data Spring boot JPA when using the same repository to save and retrieve data

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, save, vaadin

So this is what I am doind: I am filling a table with data coming from JPA. It works fine. In this table I have input fields to modify the data and then I want to save it. The employeeProjectRepository doesn't call the save method and I don't understand why...
But the notification message just after is called.

```
for (Week w : weekRepository.findAll()) {

        Grid.Column<EmployeeProject> gridColumn = grid.addComponentColumn(employeeProject -> {

            TextField amountTime = new TextField();
            amountTime.setWidth("85px");
            amountTime.setValue(String.valueOf(employeeProject.getAmountTimeEmployeeOnProject(w)));
            //Saving never called
            amountTime.addValueChangeListener(valueChangeEvent -> {
                employeeProject.setAmountTimeEmployeeOnProject(employeeProject.getProject(), w, 
     Integer.parseInt(valueChangeEvent.getValue()));
                employeeProjectRepository.save(employeeProject);
                notificationMessage.openSuccess("Saving");
            });

           return amountTime;
        });

        gridColumn.setHeader(w.getWeekNumber() + " / " + w.getYear());

    }
```

As frontend framework, I am using Vaadin 14. 
Can anyone help?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Vaadins Grid has great [editor functionality](https://vaadin.com/forum/thread/18120261/18120262), I can recommend taking advantage of it (But I also understand that it can be good to be able to directly edit with your own textfield, so no pressure there). Now to your question; Please can you show how you set the items for the grid. Are you using an in-memory data provider, or a lazyloading backend data provider? Can you  further check if the employeeProject is actually updated in DB but just not displayed in the grid?

Comment: You probably mean that save has no effect, and there can be various reasons for that. You need to check your entity. E.g. if it does not have FetchType.EAGER for this property, then you need to call initialize via Hibernate after save. Check also Cascade policy as well as orphan removal options.